# Efficiency of Order queries in Rails 3

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

So, I'd like to know which of the following is more efficient.  The best answer would actually be, how can I figure this out for myself in the future.

The two queries are:

```
# id integer 
# created_at datetime
# collection_id integer
# updated_at datetime 
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :collection
end 

Post.where(:collection_id => collection_id).order(:updated_at).last
```

vs

```
Post.where(:collection_id => collection_id).order("updated_at DESC").first
```

So, 2 part question:

1) which of those statements is more efficient?  (Unless I have a typo, they should be equivalent)

2) how could I have answered this question for myself?

I'm assuming no indexes.  I'm also curious to know if the answer changes depending on the expected size of the result set of the by collect_id portion of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Rails 3.1, both of your queries will actually run the same query on the database. Rails is smart enough to know that calling `.last` on a query should just reverse the order and limit it to a single request instead. So, the line below will really just add `ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1` to the end of your query. In other words, this line does **not** return all the records from the database, create ActiveRecord objects for each of them, and *then* return the last one, which would be much less efficient.

```
Post.where(:collection_id => collection_id).order(:updated_at).last
```

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the console, you'll see (1) what query (or queries) are actually being executed, and (2) the time it took to execute. This would be the basic way to track efficiency.

In production there are also tools like [NewRelic RPM](http://newrelic.com/) that will give you warnings/analysis of the speed/time to execute queries. I *think* the free version will do efficiency analysis, but only keeps records for the previous 30 minutes of application runtime.

Generally (but not strictly speaking), the fewer the number of queries you send, the better, partially because it involves fewer round trips between Rails and the DB.

If you want something that's also free, and perhaps more repeatable, then you can add some performance tests where you run queries over and over, timing them with each run, and just making sure that the run time for the query/controller action is less than some benchmark of your choosing, or that the average time over multiple executions is below some threshold.

This method can also be utilized as a watcher for actions that get hit most often in your app, failing if they take longer than expected. The test would only cover a simulated environment, of course, be can be used as a general indication of whether or not critical actions are getting totally out of line with expected performance.